# Parsing pseudo XML file in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I’m trying to parse text from a file that comes in a pseudo XML format. I can get a DOM document out of it when it comes in the following structure:

```
<product>
    <product_id>234567</product_id>
    <description>abc</description>
</product>
```

The problem I’m running into happens when the structure is similar to the following:

```
<product>
    <product_id>234567</product_id>
    <description>abc</description>
    <quantity 1:2>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </quantity 1:2>
        <version>1.2</version>
    <quantity 2:2>
    </quantity 2:2>
</product>
```

It generates the following exception due to the space in `<quantity 1:2>`:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException:[Fatal Error] :1:167: Element type " quantity " must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"
```

I can get around this by replacing the space with an underscore. The problem is the structure can be vary in size and include several child nodes with the same format (`<node 1:x>`) and the file can contain hundreds of structures to parse. Is there a class available that will parse text like this a return a tree-like object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It generates the following exception due to the space in `<quantity 1:2>`

This is not the root cause of the error, the root cause is, as people have already mentioned, your file format is not valid XML. A valid XML tag would look like  `<quantity attr1="val1" attr2="val2>`.

It sounds like you have no control over the file format. In this case I think the easiest way is to preprocess your file into valid XML then have DOM/SAX parser to parse it:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("pseudo.pxml");
ByteArrayOutputStream temp = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int c = -1;

while ((c=file.read()) >= 0){
   temp.write(c);
}

String xml = new String(temp.toByteArray());
xml = xml.replaceAll("([^:\s]+:[^:\s]+)", "value=\"\\1\"");

ByteArrayInputStream xmlIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());

/* use xmlIn for your XML parsers */
```

Note that I did not test this code nor is it optimized; just wanted to give you an idea.

Comment: I created a class to pre-process the file into a valid XML.

Answer (score 4):

Preprocess the file and change elements with that x:y form to `<element value="x:y"/>` then your DOM/SAX parsers will not choke.

I would suggest using a regular expression to help but [that way leads to madness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Answer (score 4):

Your file is not an XML at all, and SAX is for XML (Simple API for ***XML***). You should re-think your structure so you can do something like:

```
<quantity myAttr="1.2">
    <version>1.2</version>
</quantity>
<quantity myAttr="1.x">
    <version>1.1</version>
</quantity>
<version>1.0</version>
```

Or something like that.